# Regex Lookahead & Lookbehind Matching

Tags: java, regex

I need to take a string and extract every instance of a pattern and only the pattern.

`String test = "This is a test string to experiment with regex by separating every instance of the word test and words that trail test";`

So now the pattern would have to find the word `test` as well as any words ahead and behind it that are not `test`. So basically it would have to result in 3 instances of this pattern being found.

The 3 results that I'm expecting are as follows:

1. `This is a test string to experiment with regex by separating every instance of the word`
2. `test and words that trail`
3. `test`

I've played around with postive lookahead and negative lookahead on [gskinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) but no luck yet.

Comment: Is this even possible with Regex? May have to design it your own.

Comment: Funny thing is that I was designing it on my own for 2 weeks before I decided to change over to doing it with regex lol

Comment: Shouldn't the second and third be `string to experiment with regex by separating every instance of the word test and words that trail` and `that trail test` respectively?

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it I think you're right. Maybe post an alternative answer with the above implementation if possible?

Comment: A pattern search starts, where the last match ends. This means you can't find overlapping matches with regex alone. You can do so by looking for test and start searching from there on, but that makes regex redundant in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
(\s*\b(?!test\b)[a-z]+\b\s*)*test(\s*\b(?!test\b)[a-z]+\b\s*?)*
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33eto).

In Java, I would replace `[a-z]` with `\p{L}`, but regexr does not support Unicode properties. `\p{L}` is a [Unicode code point with the property letter](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop), this will match every letter in any language.

**Explanation:**

`(\s*\b(?!test\b)[a-z]+\b\s*)*` is matching a series of words that are not "test". This is ensured by the negative lookahead assertion `(?!test\b)`.

`test` is matching "test"

and at the end the same again: match a series of words that are not "test" with again `(\s*\b(?!test\b)[a-z]+\b\s*?)*`

Comment: "In Java from Version 7..." - I don't get that.  Unicode support was much improved in Java 7,  but it has always supported `\p{L}`.

Comment: @AlanMoore removed that limitation, I know the there was a major improvement in 7, but I was not sure and did not check if `\p{L}` worked before version 7.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up my comment, I could imagine splitting your test string with the pattern `\btest\b` and then join the string parts left and right

```
String parts[] = test.split("\btest\b", -1);
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length - 1; ++i)
    System.out.println(parts[i] + "test" + parts[i + 1]);
```